# Weierstrass Approximation Theorem Question

Tags: analysis

Is it possible to prove the trigonometric version of the Weiestrass Approximation Theorem (functions in $S^1$) using the regular Weierstrass Approximation Theorem (functions in $\mathrm{C}([a,b], \mathbb{R})$) by composing the polynomial with a mapping from $[a,b]$ to $[0,2\pi]$ ? If yes, can you show such mapping?

Edit:sorry, I wanted to say $S^1$.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the trigonometric Weierstrass theorem, it does not say that any function in $C^0([0,2\pi])$ is uniformly approximate by polynomials, but rather that any $2\pi$-periodic continuous function is uniformly approximate by sums of $\sin$ and $\cos$. I know that one can derive the algebraic Weierstrass theorem from the trigonometric one, using Chebychev polynomials, but I don't know if the other way is possible.

Comment: @C.Falcon: Those would be the trigonometric polynomials...

Comment: @copper.hat Unless I don't get your point, that is why I said that I don't know the answer to the OP's question. I only know that Chebychev polynomials and the regular Weierstrass theorem gives the trigonometric one.

Comment: @C.Falcon: If I understood the question correctly, the OP was asking if one could use the regular approximation theorem (on $[a,b]$) to prove the fact that the trigonometric polynomials uniformly approximate the continuous functions on $S^1$. This does not suggest a misunderstanding of the trigonometric Weierstrass theorem...

Comment: @copper.hat You are probably right, I was just surprised that the OP never mentionned "periodic" or $\mathbb{S}^1$ but only $C([0,2\pi],\mathbb{R})$ that is why I suspected a misunderstanding on the trigonometric Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $f\in C[0,2\pi]$ with $f(0)=f(2\pi),$ let $f_1(x)=(f(x)+f(\pi -x))/2$ and $f_2(x)=(f(x)-f(\pi -x))/2.$

The function $h_1(x)=\cos^{-1} x$ is a continuous bijection from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,\pi].$ So both $h_1$ and $h_1^{-1}$ are continuous.  The function $g_1(y)=f_1(h_1(y))$ is continuous on $[-1,1]$. Now $g_1(y)=g_1( -y)$ for all $y, $ so $g_1$ can be uniformly approximated by a polynomial $p_1$  with $p_1(-y)=p_1(y)$ for all $y.$ Therefore $f_1(z)$, for all $x\in [0,2\pi]$ is uniformly approximated by    $p_1(h^{-1}(x))=p_1(\cos x).$

Similarly, $h_2(x)=\pi /2+\sin^{-1}x$ is a continuous bijection from $[-1,1]$ to $[0,\pi]$ so we can uniformly approximate $g_2(x)=f_2(h_2(x))$ by $p_2(\sin x)$ with some polynomial $p_2$  such that $p_2(-y)=-p_2(y)$ for all $y$.  So $f_2(x)$ is uniformly approximated by $p_2(\sin x)$ for all $x\in [0,2\pi].$

So $f=f_1+f_2$ is uniformly approximated by $p_1(\cos x)+p_2(\sin x)$ over $x\in [0,2\pi ].$

Appendix: Regarding approximating even (odd) functions by even (odd) polynomials: For $g\in C[-1,1] :$

(1). If  $g$ is even: Approximate $g(\sqrt {|x|})$ for $x\in [0,1]$   by polynomial $q(x).$ Then $g(x)=g((\sqrt {|x|})^2)$ is approximated by $q(x^2)$ for $x\in [-1,1].$

(2). If g is odd: Approximate $g(x)$ by polynomial $q_1(x)$ for $x\in [0,1].$ Then $q_2(x)=q_1(x)-q_1(0)$ approximates $g(x)$ for $x\in [0,1]$ because $g(0)=0.$ Now $q_2(x)=xq_3(x)$ with $q_3$ polynomial,  because $q_2(x)=0.$ Let $j(x)=q_3(|x|)$ for $x\in [-1,1].$ By (1), $ j(x)$ is approximated by $q_4(x^2)$ for some polynomial $q_4.$  So $xq_4(x^2)$ approximates $g(x)$ for $x\in [-1,1].$

Comment: I have a question: to me it seems that the domain of f should be [0, pi], because of the functions f1 and f2, why can we pass from [0,pi] to [0, 2pi] ? In the case that there's such error in the solution, I think that the functions m(x) = 2*arccos(x) and n(x) = pi+2*arcsin(x), both from [-1,1] to [0, 2pi] might work.

Comment: $g_1(y)$ is uniformly approximated on  $[-1,1]$  by $p_1(y)=q_1(y^2)$  with polynomial  $q_1.$  So for $x\in [0,2\pi], \quad  f_1(x)=g_1(\cos x)$ is approximated by $p_1(\cos x)=q_1(\cos^2 x).$  Similarly for $f_2$